# Nested foreach loops to install printers

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach, scripting, break

I have a need to install multiple printers to multiple servers and was wanting to script this so that it would only need to be configured once.

I am using PowerShell to query 2 CSV files; 1 to get a list of computers to install printers too and the other to list the Name, IP, Driver, Location of the needed printers. I am using 2 `foreach` loops to accomplish this and a `break` to try to get it to loop correctly.

Currently with the `break :outer` where it is the first PC gets all printers installed. If I move it to inside the `foreach ($printer in $printers)` loop it will only install the first printer to all computers.

Thank you for any assistance that anyone can provide.

```
$computerfile = Import-Csv C:\computerlist.csv
$printers = Import-Csv C:\printers2.csv 

foreach ($computer in $computerfile) {
    "computer: $computer"
    :outer
    foreach ($printer in $printers) {
        Add-PrinterPort -ComputerName $computer.Name -Name $printer.IP -PrinterHostAddress $printer.IP
        Add-Printer -ComputerName $computer.Name -Name $printer.Name -DriverName $printer.Driver -PortName $printer.IP -ShareName $printer.Name -Location $printer.Location
        Set-printer -ComputerName $computer.Name -Name $printer.Name -Shared $false -Published $true
    }
    break :outer
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the break :outer ?

Comment: `break` statement you can use to **immediately exit** `Foreach`, `For`, `While`, `Do`, or `Switch` statements. Omit it at all.

Comment: Aside from perhaps doing some error handling which might be a good idea in case there are remoting or permissions issues.....There is no reason to break the loops prematurely here. For Each Server Install Each printer. Remove the labels and the break. Are you getting errors? Not sure what the question is here.

Comment: YanivK - I didn;t think the 2 foreach loops would cycle through all of the PCs without seperating out the loop but you are right; The code works fine by removing both the ":outer" and "break :outer" lines. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the break :outer from your code.

What is happening is that the first loop starts running, and enters the second loop **only once!** because of the break, and jumps to the next computer.

Comment: It was my pleasure :)